# how do i put parameters in this swagger function?

Tags: node.js, swagger

I wanted to know how to add parameters to this swagger url

```
import Swagger from 'swagger-client';

 const BACKEND_PORT = 8080;

 const swagger = Swagger(`http://localhost:${BACKEND_PORT}/api/apidocs`);

 export const calculateFirstMillion = (formValues) => {
     return swagger.then(client => {
         return client.apis.calculate.PMT()
            .then(({ body }) => body)
     })
 }
```

Comment: Wrong site? This is for English.

Comment: I wanted to know how to add parameters to this url

Comment: [edit] the question to make it in English.

Comment: Ok, edited to english

Comment: Can you clarify what is wrong with your current code? Are you getting an error? If yes, please post the error message. Or does the code not work as expected? If so, then explain  what results you expect and what you actually get. The more details, the easier it will be for someone to help you.

Comment: there is no error message, i just wanted to send a body for this request.